# Access combobox en cascada en formulario tabular

Tags: ms-access

He trabajado muchas veces con combobox en cascada, el típico caso de país/ciudad.

En esta ocasión estoy trabajando en un formulario tabular, lo que no había hecho antes, y el problema es que al cambiar el rowsource del combobox desde VBA me cambia el de todas las columnas y las filas que tienen diferente país la ciudad desaparece.

En la primera imagen podrán ver cómo se cargan bien los valores de ciudad, y país. En la segunda imagen se selecciona un país para agregar un nuevo registro (o para modificar uno existente), y pueden notar que en la primera fila desaparece la ciudad, pues pertenece a un país diferente.

[image: pantalla correcta solo al ingresar]

[image: se selecciona un país en cualquir registro y desaparecen en los otros registros las ciudades si el país es diferente]

¿hay alguna forma de manejar combobox en cascada en un formulario tabular?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir unos pantallazos de ejemplo? Y también cómo te gustaría que fuera (visualmente digo). Pero, de primeras, creo que en un formulario tabular, todos los combobox del mismo campo van a adaptarse según el registro activo...

Comment: ya agregué las imágenes, lo que indicas efectivamente es lo que está ocurriendo, pero me pregunto si hay alguna manera de hacer que funcione bien, de relacionar la ciudad solamente con el país de su misma fila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede hacer lo que quieres. Al trabajar en formato tabular, en realidad es como abrir varias veces simultáneamente el mismo formulario.

Tu lista de ciudades, mediante VBA, se filtra según el país seleccionado  en el registro activo (esto es, el registro en el que estés operando actualmente).

Por eso te desaparecen, visualmente, valores (pero siguen ahí, el dato no se pierde). He hecho una pequeña demo donde esto se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que según cambio de registro, el combobox de Ciudad se actualiza con las opciones disponibles, pero como tienes varias copias del mismo formulario abiertas a la vez, cualquier cambio de formulario afecta a todo lo que ves.

Es como si los dos tenemos abierto el mismo libro por la misma página y tú dibujas una línea roja, pero quieres que **a la vez** yo la vea azul. Es imposible, es la misma hoja en el mismo momento del tiempo.

He probado también con formularios continuos a ver si se le podía engañar de alguna manera, pero pasa exactamente lo mismo.

Si das con la respuesta, te sugeriría que la compartieras pero dudo mucho que se pueda, (o al menos no de una manera fácil).

Si de verdad es necesario, lo más sencillo que veo es trabajar con un único formulario si quieres tener esa lista filtrada.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Pues hay una manera, algo retorcida, pero puede causar el efecto que deseas, pero necesitas un poco de programación y puede que tengas que modificar alguna relación, pero mira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, para que todo esto funcione, tus datos tienen que estar bien relacionados, tienes que modificar los filtros bien mediante SQL con la propiedad OrigenFila y necesitas algo de código:

Puedes mirar el proceso aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access

Básicamente se trata de convertir en textbox el campo y meter un combobox no vinculado (unbound) en el que sí metes que se filtr la lista de ciudades según el país.

En mi código, el control `Ciudad` es el que se almacena en la tabla y el control `cmb_ciudad` es el combobox sin vincular que muestra las ciudades.

El truco está en que visualmente ves un combobox que, en realidad, no está vinculado, y ahí es donde seleccionas la ciudad (puedes filtrar ese combobox como siempre). Cuando selecciones una opción, envía el valor seleccionado mediante VBA al campo `Ciudad`, que es el que verdaderamente lo almacena.

Ese combobox especial, lo he colocado **detrás** del campo Ciudad, para que visualmente parezcan que son el mismo, pero en realidad no es así. Con lo que interactúa el usuario es el combobox no vinculado, no con el campo Ciudad.

El código es:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Ciudad_Enter()
Me.cmb_ciudad.SetFocus 'cuando el usuario entre en el campo ciudad, automáticamente desviamos el foco a nuestro combobox personalizado cmb_ciudad
End Sub

Private Sub cmb_ciudad_AfterUpdate()
Me.Ciudad.Value = Me.cmb_ciudad.Value 'enviamos el valor seleccionado en el combobox al campo Ciudad, que es el vinculado.
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.Painting = False

Me.cmb_ciudad.Requery 'Siempre actualizamos lista al cambiar de registro.

If Len(Me.Ciudad.Value) = 0 Then 'si no hay ciudad, posiblemente sea un registro nuevo, con lo cual queremos que el combobox empiece en blanco
    Me.cmb_ciudad.Value = ""
Else
    Me.cmb_ciudad.Value = Me.Ciudad.Value 'queremos que el combobox mueste el valor que ya está almacenado en el campo Ciudad
End If

Me.Painting = True
End Sub

Private Sub País_AfterUpdate()
' Cuando seleccionamos un país, queremos que nuestro combobox fantasma actualice su lista
Me.Painting = False
Me.cmb_ciudad.Requery
Me.Painting = True
End Sub
```

De todas formas, valora positivamente si complicarte tanto la vida merece la pena o no. Los formularios continuos y tabulares están pensados para **ver** datos de forma cómoda y compacta, no para **editar**.

He subido una copia de la bbdd de pruebas que he usado para desarrollar esto, por si quieres ver cómo lo tengo configurado para que funcione:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18H5e5Q1A_2VeG4ppeHwW3W8KD3RjETbV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Genial!!!, yo sospechaba que alguien podía haber encontrado una forma, voy a probarlo, mil gracias

Comment: ¡Funciona perfecto!, había estado dando vueltas a una solución parecida pero no había logrado qu funcionara, muchas gracias